# Setting the background color of a contentbyte itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

MVC3 VB.NET application using Itextsharp. I have a section of code that generates a pdf file everything looks great but I would like to alternate the line colors in that pdf file between 2 color so that the values are easy to follow for the person looking at it. Is there a way to set the background color of a whole line based on font size to a set color? A function I would be using this in is below:

```
    For Each _reg_ In _reg
                Dim _registrant As reg_info = _reg_
                If y_line1 <= 30 Then
                    doc.NewPage()
                    _Page = _Page + 1
                    y_line1 = 670
                End If

                If y_line1 = 670 Then
                    cb.BeginText()
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 6)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, _datePrinted + "  " + _timePrinted, 500, 770, 0)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Page Number" + " " + _Page, 600, 770, 0)
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 8)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, _reportHead + " Overrides ", 304, 720, 0)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "First Name", 20, 700, 0)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Last Name", 80, 700, 0)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Last Four", 160, 700, 0)
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Email Address", 300, 700, 0)

                    cb.EndText()
                End If

                cb.BeginText()
                cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 8)
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, _registrant.first_name, 20, y_line1, 0)
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, _registrant.last_name, 80, y_line1, 0)
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, _registrant.last_four_social, 160, y_line1, 0)
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, _registrant.email, 300, y_line1, 0)
                _total += 1
                cb.EndText()
                y_line1 = y_line1 - 15
            Next
```

I thought about just setting the background color of the line by using the y_line1 and using a modulus to determine if the color should be grey or white. But I have found no code samples anywhere about how to set a whole line background color.. Any ideas????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of "background color" in the PDF spec in relation to text. Anything that looks like a background color, even a table, is just text drawn on top of a rectangle (or some other shape).

To draw a rectangle you just call the `Rectangle` method on your `PdfContentByte` object. It takes a lower left x,y and a width and a height. The color is determined by a previous call to one of the color fills such as `SetColorFill()`.

When working with the raw canvas its recommended that you also use `SaveState()` and `RestoreState()`. Since the fill commands are shared between objects but mean different things these can help avoid confusion. `SaveState()` sets a flag allowing you to undo all graphics state changes when you call `RestoreState()`.

The code below is a full working VB.Net 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 that shows off the above. It creates a sample file on the desktop with a line of text repeated 7 times. Each line toggles back and forth between two background colors. Additionally it draws a stroke around the line of text to simulate a border.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//Test file that we'll create
        Dim TestFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TestFile.pdf")
        ''//Test String that we'll repeat
        Dim TestString = "It was the best of times..."
        ''//Create an array of our test string
        Dim TestArray = {TestString, TestString, TestString, TestString, TestString, TestString, TestString}

        ''//Create our generic font
        Dim BF_Times = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)

        ''//Standard PDF setup, change as needed for your stream type
        Using FS As New FileStream(TestFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Using Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
                Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
                    Doc.Open()

                    ''//Grab the raw content object
                    Dim cb = writer.DirectContent
                    ''//Set our starter Y coordinate
                    Dim y = 670
                    ''//Loop through our string collection
                    For I = 0 To (TestArray.Count - 1)
                        ''//Store the current graphics state so that we can unwind it later
                        cb.SaveState()
                        ''//Set the fill color based on eve/odd
                        cb.SetColorFill(If(I Mod 2 = 0, BaseColor.GREEN, BaseColor.BLUE))
                        ''//Optional, set a border
                        cb.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK)
                        ''//Draw a rectangle. NOTE: I'm subtracting 5 from the y to account for padding
                        cb.Rectangle(0, y - 5, Doc.PageSize.Width, 15)
                        ''//Draw the rectangle with a border. NOTE: Use cb.Fill() to draw without the border
                        cb.FillStroke()
                        ''//Unwind the graphics state
                        cb.RestoreState()

                        ''//Flag to begin text
                        cb.BeginText()
                        ''//Set the font
                        cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 6)
                        ''//Write some text
                        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, TestArray(I), 0, y, 0)
                        ''//Done writing text
                        cb.EndText()

                        ''//Decrease the y accordingly
                        y -= 15
                    Next


                    Doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```