# Color the background of a piece of text in a PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

How do I set the background color of a piece of text in a PDF document using iTextSharp without taking a form field?

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15343400/303685) uses a `FormField`, which according to me is an overkill and too long-winded a way to do something really simple.

Is there a simple way of coloring the background of a piece of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying, I have come to the conclusion that there are 3 ways to do this other than using the `FormField` (which is the fourth way and how to do that is already linked in the question):

1) Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585660/303685) to another similar question, it appears as though there is no concept of a background color for text in the PDF specification. Therefore, one has to draw a rectangle at an absolute position before drawing the text (at that position).

This is like drawing on a Win32 `DeviceContext`.

2) You can draw a table and set the background color of the cell in which you want a background color.

3) You can write a chunk. The `Chunk` class has a method named `SetBackground()`. This doesn't look very nice because it doesn't let you control the padding around the text and between the borders of the box. You can control how far above the baseline the bottom of the text will appear by calling the `chunk.SetTextRise(float f)` method but that's about it. Still, it's a fast and easy way to get things done if you don't want too much beautification.

Comment: You overlooked the `onGenericTag()` method.

Comment: wow, you seriously asked a question and then answered it within 5 minutes, just so you could mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `SetBackground` that is available in the `Chunk` class. There are two variations of this method: one that takes default padding and one that allows you to change the padding.

If you use the `onGenericTag()` method on a `Chunk`, you can draw a custom background (and do much more). For instance: you'd use `onGenericTag()` if you want to draw a rectangle with rounded corners. See my answer to your duplicate question [Draw a rectangle at the *current position* and then get its position coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006925/draw-a-rectangle-at-the-current-position-and-then-get-its-position-coordinates)