# Draw a rectangle at the *current position* and then get its position coordinates

Tags: c#, itext

So, I am writing some text into a PDF file using iTextSharp.

After having added a few paragraphs and phrases to the PDF document, I want to:

Draw the next piece of text on top of a rectangle that has a fill color, say, red.

I can compute the required width and height that the rectangle must have based on the text metrics of the text I am going to write on top of it. But how do I tell the `Rectangle` API what is top and left coordinates are, as in *where* it must be drawn?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are looking for the [`Chunk.setBackground()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setBackground%28com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor%29) method. This draws a colored background underneath some text. There's also a variation of the method that takes extra parameters if you need a larger or smaller rectangle.

Suppose that you don't want a colored rectangle, but a custom type of shape, then you'd use the page event [onGenericTag()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEvent.html#onGenericTag%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Document,%20com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20java.lang.String%29). See [Chunk > Generic tag](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=206) for more info.

The `onGenericTag()` method is triggered every time a `Chunk` that is marked as generic (using the [`setGenericTag()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setGenericTag%28java.lang.String%29) method) is rendered to a page. Your implementation of the page event can then use the `Rectangle` value that is passed to the event method. It is important to understand that a single `Chunk` marked as a generic tag can result in multiple invocations of this method: if the contents of a single `Chunk` needs to be distributed over different lines, the event will be triggered as many times as there are lines (giving you a separate `Rectangle` value for every separate line).